# Which set is greater in cardinality?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Which set is greater in cardinality, the set of all functions from $\mathbb R$(the real numbers) into $\mathbb N$(the natural numbers) or the set of all functions from $\mathbb N$ into $\mathbb R$? I have a feeling that the set of all functions from $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb N$ is equinumerous to the power set of $\mathbb R$ and that the set of all functions from $\mathbb N$ into $\mathbb R$ is equinumerous to the set $\mathbb R$. Can someone please provide me an answer with proof?

Comment: $c^{\aleph_0} = (2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0 \cdot \aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0} = c$ while $\aleph_0^c \ge 2^c$.

Comment: This is impossible to read. Maybe some line breaks are in order? Also, a better title, please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This answer is elementary: it doesn't require any cardinal arithmetic beyond Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein.

We'll use $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$ when convenient, since it's simpler. Let's take $\mathbb{N} = \{1,2,\dots\}$.

The set of functions $\mathbb{N} \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is equinumerous with $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$. Indeed, given a subset $A$ of the naturals, we can create a unique function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ which sends $n \mapsto A$; conversely, given a function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ we can create a unique subset of the naturals by taking the elements of $f(1)$, $f(2)$, $f(3)$, and so on, and distinguishing them by powers of primes:
$$\{2^a, 3^b, 5^c, \dots : a \in f(1), b \in f(2), c \in f(3), \dots \}$$
So by Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein, there is a bijection between $\mathbb{N} \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.

However, $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N}$ is at least as big as $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$. The injection is easy: given a set $A$ of reals, define a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N}$ by $r \mapsto 1$ if $r \in A$, and $r \mapsto 2$ otherwise.

---

In fact, $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N}$ is exactly as big as $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$; you can prove this by using the same "powers of primes" trick as above (using $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$), but it goes one level deeper. Exercise for you.

Answer (score 19):

In fact, the number of functions from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb R$ is the same as the number of reals.  Remember the number of functions $A \to B$ is $|B|^{|A|}$ because you have $|B|$ choices of where to send each element of $A$, so make that choice $|A|$ times.  Since $|\Bbb R|=2^{\aleph_0}$ the number of functions from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb R$ is $(2^{\aleph_o})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_o\cdot \aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_o}$.  The number of functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb N$ is $\aleph_0^{(2^{\aleph_0})}$ which is equivalent to the power set of $\Bbb R$

Comment: This uses the law $(X^Y)^Z = X^{Y\cdot Z}$ for ___cardinals___ $X$, $Y$, and $Z$.

Comment: and the fact that ${\aleph_o}.{\aleph_0}={\aleph_0}$